# jQuery / JavaScript, why do I need to wrap variables in $() to use them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a map on an array of elements. The callback function takes the index and the value at that position in the array.

If I wrap the array element that the callback receives in $(), it behaves as I expect. If I use it without wrapping it in $(), it gives an error.

```
var nonHiddenElements = $( "form :input" ).not(':hidden');

nonHiddenElements.map(function(index, element){

    input_id = $(element).attr('id');  // this works

    input_id = element.attr('id') ;    // this gives an error

})
```

Can someone explain how this works. 
Is this a jQuery quirk, or a JavScript thing?

What type of objects does my nonHiddenElements array contain exactly? 
What is element that gets passed to the callback?
And mainly what is the $() doing?

Comment: presumably because it's the **name** or another kind of identifier of the element that is returned, and not the actual DOM object itself.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Where can I read up on this sort of thing. It seems implicit that I know these things in advance of every tutorial I read.

Comment: Have you tried element.id? `.attr()` is a jquery keyword. In order to use that you need to call jquery by using `$(element)`.

Comment: @wobbily_col I'm pretty sure it's in the documentation of the appropriate jQuery function.

Comment: `$(element)` returns a `jQuery` object that wraps the `DOM element`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Actually it *is* the actual DOM object itself, and that's why you need to wrap it: it's not a jQuery object.

Comment: FYI, you can simply `element.id`.

Comment: There is a lot of Jquery documentation, and like I say, it seems assumed that you will know all this before starting.

Comment: It's assumed that if you want to know what a function's parameter is you know how to look it up in the API.

Comment: @Juhana. Thanks for the least helpful comment so far. Its not a function that I need to look up. Its an overall overview of how everything fits together. What type of objects are being returned. I guess you didn't pay too much attention to the question.

Comment: But looking up the `element` parameter in `.map()` would tell you that.

Comment: @Juhana that makes sense too. (I think it's still a related issue - it's actual type is not the expected type.)

Comment: @Juhana. I just looked up map, as I had done with many other functions before I posted my question. No explanation of jQuery prototype objects, and convenience methods (like the accepted answer). Now if you had pointed me to the jQuery learning centre page where all this is explained, then the map documentation might actually make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand how jQuery actually works. I will try to explain it briefly.

`$` is nothing but a normal javascript function. `jQuery` === `$`, is just a function with a fancy name. This function does a lot of different things, depending on what you pass in it. For example if you pass a string it will be treated as CSS selector and jQuery internals will try to find corresponding DOM elements. Or if you pass a string starting with `<` and ending with `>` jQuery will create a new DOM element by provided HTML string.

Now if you pass a DOM element or NodeCollection of DOM elements, it/they will be wrapped into jQuery instances so that they can have a jQuery prototype methods. There are many prototype methods jQuery offers. For example `text`, `css`, `append`, `attr` - those are all methods of jQuery prototype. They are defined basically like this (simplified):

```
jQuery.prototype.text = function() { ... }
```

Normal DOM elements don't have those convenient methods jQuery provides. And inside of methods like `map` or `each` if you check `this` value or `element` parameter like you do, you will see that they are actually not jQuery instances:

```
element instanceof jQuery // => false
```

and of course you can't use instance methods with not an instance.

So in order to use jQuery prototype methods you need have a jQuery instance, which you can obtain if you call jQuery function with DOM element passed in it:

```
$(element) instanceof jQuery // true
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there further documentation I can read about this stuff? It seems to be implied that you will know all this stuff in advance.

Comment: I would recommend to go through [jQuery learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). And also to get familiar with native javascript [prototypical inheritance](http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance#the-prototype) concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a programming language.

jQuery is a JavaScript Library.

With jQuery:

```
$("some element")
```

In native JavaScript you would have to do something like this.

```
getElementById('elementByID')
```

Explained in detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

MDN is a great resource for beginners.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript